# Change Postion of Tag "Li" in "ul"

Tags: jquery

I'm new at JQuery. I want to change this Tag li with class "vorLast li" and class "second".

Here is my Code in HTML:

```
<ul id="my_list">
    <li class="first">
        <a href="" class="class_a">First</a>
    </li>
    <li class="vorLast li">
        <a href="" class="vorLast">VorLast</a>
    </li>
    <li class="second">
        <a href="" class="class_a">Second</a>
    </li>   

    <li class="last li">
        <a href="" class="last">Last</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And in main.js I want to use function **insertBefore** to change this Li.I have tried:

```
$(document).ready( ()=> {
  const liLast= $(".last .li");
  const liVorlast =$(".vorLast .li");
  liVorlast.insertBefore(liLast)
});
```

Thank all for read and help :)

Comment: Have a look at how selectors work. `.last .li` won't select/match anything.

Comment: you should select by using `tag.className` so in your case it would be `li.last`

Comment: i have spaces in between :D. Just so : const liLast= $(".last.li"); is worked :D